# Storing multiple artist info from API into file (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, file, api

I really need help. I'm using an API to gather artist information depending on the artist name (`$artist_name = $_GET['artistname']`).

I need to add the API results into an array and store it into a file (NOT a database). This file will be ever growing as more and more artist entries are added to it.

Once I have an array in the file, I need to be able to read it and parse it. That way I can display the information without repeatedly using the API.

I have figured out how to add an array to a file with one entry, but how can I add more keys into the same array?

This is what I'm using now...

```
//ARRAY
$artist_info_location_array = array($artist_name => $location_entry);

//FILE
$artist_location_file = get_template_directory()."/Database/Artists/info-location.json";

//GET ARRAY FILE
$get_location_array[] = json_decode(file_get_contents($artist_location_file), true);

if (is_array($get_location_array)) {
    if (!array_key_exists($artist_name, $get_location_array)) {
        file_put_contents($artist_location_file, json_encode($artist_info_location_array));
    }
}
```

It prints this to the file:

```
{"Imagine Dragons":"Las Vegas, NV, US"}
```

That's cool, but I need to be able to add more artists to this SAME ARRAY. So the result should look like this with another artist added:

```
{"Imagine Dragons":"Las Vegas, NV, US", "Adele":"London, UK"}
```

That shows Imagine Dragons and Adele both added to the same array.

Can someone help me "append" or add extra keys and values to the same array as they are added to the file?

Thanks.

---

EDIT 1 (In response to Martin):
I have a panel on the side of the page in question. This panel will show relevant information about the artist that has been searched for. Let's say you search for the artist "Adele". **$artist_name** would = **Adele**.

Lets say I'd like to store all artist locations, I would use the example I posted to store each artist location in the file called **info-location.json** ($artist_location_file).

So every time an artist page is loaded, the artist name and location would be added to the array in the file.

If my example doesn't make any sense, please show me an example on how to add multiple entries into ONE ARRAY. I am using an API and would like to cache this information to use instead of requesting the API on each load.

Hope this makes sense. :)

Comment: [The Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) Parameter 3 set to `FILE_APPEND` Although the whole idea sounds very hinky

Comment: I've done this and the FILE_APPEND flag actually adds another "array" to the end of the file. For example: {"Imagine Dragons":"Las Vegas, NV, US"}{"Adele":"London, UK"}. I need the other artists added to the actual array. What does hinky mean? If there's a better way, please share with me :)

Comment: What defines what the array is, how would you establish which artists belong in which arrays, and more importantly, how will your file establish this? If you only have one array of places/artists then you can simply add new ones and assume they're all in the same array?

Comment: Hinky - (of an object) unreliable.

Comment: @Martin I edited my question to hopefully answer your question. Thanks

Comment: @RiggsFolly Absolutely, I agree! I need a better (and working) solution. I simply need to cache this API info into a file that I can read later on. My question is unique to all the examples I've read because I have multiple KEYS and VALUES that are all different that need to be added to the same array file. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you not doing this with a database? I'm not sure, but if this file was to be live and used, then it will be being opened and read by numerous instances and sounds like all sorts of *potential* hassle with read/writes .

Comment: In answer to your question, how about an approach of reimporting the file, adding the new data to the file array and then re-exporting it as a nested JSON array?

Comment: @Martin I'd like to use a database but my hosting plan currently doesn't allow accessing MySQL / database entries. It's a pain that I'm dealing with now, but in the meantime, I'd like to utilize whatever other methods there are to caching API requests into an array of some sort. I know it's ideal to use a database, but is it possible to store this info into a file? Thanks

Comment: Read my lips - Database, Datebase, Database

Comment: The problem with files is that the data you want to save and write and then read is happening at all sorts of different times, potentially simultaneously, what if someone is trying to read the file at the same time someone else is writing to the file? There are a multitude of issues and potential issues here. Prime reason to database it up. Even if you can't set a database on your current hosting plan, you can explore having a database *only* with another host and then remote logging into the database and working from there.

Comment: So reimporting the file using file_get_contents($array_file) ... and from that point, how to add the new data to the array that's already in the file? Then to re-export, using json_encode($array_name)... Sorry I'm just confused with the whole process. It should be pretty straight forward...

Comment: @RiggsFolly Preaching to the choir, brother. My current situation doesn't allow creation/manipulation of database files. So I'm exploring other options. I have potentially 100's of thousands of unique artist information to store, but I'm trying to get at least 2 of those stored to get me started.

Comment: 1) JSON load the file. 2) add the new data to the loaded array 3) Save JSON data back to file.

Comment: @Martin Yea but 100,000+ items in an array. **See memory go boom** and **see response times go into a toilet**

Comment: @Martin Wow that makes sense, I didn't even think of that. Thanks for hipping me to that possibility. I know I have my hands full. I'm trying to work with what I have at the time and the site is for experimenting purposes. So the chance of multiple people requesting the file at once is not an issue. But I understand where you're going...

Comment: @RiggsFolly Would make for some amazing fire works! But other than that, isn't a great approach to this whole thing. I need a hosting upgrade/change.

Comment: As a minimum you are going to have to break the file into multiple files, for example 26 files one for each starting letter of Artists name

Comment: @Martin Thanks, I'll try something like that.

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah there will probably be a performance hit, but as a systemic approach it should work, but far less ideal than a database. Your further approach of division into starting letters is helpful.

Comment: _“My current situation doesn't allow creation/manipulation of database files”_ – what exactly does that mean? Cheap hosting package with no database available? At least something like SQLite should be available in most configurations …

Comment: @RiggsFolly That's a fair idea. Let me check out an approach to that and see if I can get something working.

Comment: what about naming the files by artist, so `adele.json` lists all of her gigs? etc. You can do a similar naming structure for locations as well, this will break the files into numerous smaller files and will improve file access

Comment: @CBroe It means that being cheap simply for experimenting isn't worth it. I'm used to using BlueHost for my projects. This is something personal and I went with *cough*GoDaddy*cough* for hosting. Didn't do proper research before I committed. *Sigh*

Comment: @Martin That is one thing that I wrote down as a possibility. I feel better about that now, thanks. My only concern was having a ton of files (one for each artist) dumped into a folder. But I guess that shouldn't be an issue as I'm only accessing the file if it's requested from a user. I think I may have to do it this way instead of combining the info into one array/file. :)

Comment: breaking the data into smaller parts will really help you if you're dealing with 100k+ rows. Also recommended to put locations and artists in different folders!!

Comment: @Martin Definitely. I have info such as (but not limited to): Years active, familiarity, hotness, related genres, location, recent albums, photos, news...etc... All the way to very detailed track information including - BPM (tempo) information, chord info, similar songs based on rhythm, etc. It gets VERY deep. But I needed to start simple. And breaking down the info into separate folders and files may be the way to go if a database isn't available.

Comment: GoDaddy has databases I am sure I have used it once and they had databases

Comment: That much detail you ***need a database*** because you can't search the data if it's in 15 files, all different data for one artist, say Adele then you'll need to open maybe 15 different files to get the information you want, it will very quickly become top heavy, file opening and access is one of the slowest parts of machine code.

Comment: @RiggsFolly They do have Linux and CPanel plans. I'm on a managed plan for some odd reason (my fault). I'm an extremely technical person and I can't deal with the limitations. And GoDaddy support sucks. They're not very helpful. But I'll have to purchase a new plan I guess.

Comment: @Martin *Sigh*. That's the reality I'm facing at this point. I'll be switching this domain to BlueHost on Friday. Then at least I can access MySQL and play with databases instead of trying to work around this issue. But at least I know my dream is a possibility as long as I'm storing and accessing the data correctly.

Comment: ON the plus side, if you save all your data as JSON encoded files then it should be pretty straight forward to upload the data into the database, once you get it sorted!

Comment: @Martin Very true. In the meantime, I'm going to work on accessing the API methods, gathering (or at least just accessing) the information I need and once I'm ready, I can harass you guys on dumping that into a database (if I can't figure it out myself). I appreciate your optimism! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding your question, but if you just want to read in a json file, add an associative array key to it if it does not exist and then put it back into the json file why dont you do something like this:

```
if (is_array($get_location_array)) {
if (!array_key_exists($artist_name, $get_location_array)) {
    $get_location_array[$artist_name] = $location;
    file_put_contents($artist_location_file, json_encode($artist_info_location_array));
    }
}
```

`file_put_contents` will overwrite an existing file (pretty sure). But your best option is to use a database. If you can't do that, then I suggest to prevent writing to the file while you are doing this I suggest you use `fopen`, `flock`, and `fwrite` and then `fclose`

Comment: Thanks for the example. Yes, file_put_contents() overwrites the file unless you use the flag FILE_APPEND. I've tried appending and it simply won't work for what I'm trying to do. I'll check out fopen, flock, etc. Thank you!

Comment: I suggest just overwriting it. You have the file in a array already : `$get_location_array = json_decode(file_get_contents($artist_location_file), true);` just add to the array ` $get_location_array[$key] = $value ` encode is and rewrite the file

Comment: Dish_Rex, your simple solution is working. Thank you! This will work for now until I am able to work with databases.

Comment: @ItsMeMike awesome! If it works please accept the answer. That would be greatly appreciated.